# how to submit form after print iframe

Tags: jquery, printing, form-submit

i want to submit the form after i frame is printed, when i click on the event box class , jquery should find the form and submit it at the time of submit,

the problem is after printing form is not submitted.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on("click", ".event-box", function () {
        var obj = {
            classevent_id: $(this).find("input:hidden[name=classevent_id]").val(),
            member_id: $(this).find("input:hidden[name=member_id]").val(),
            classname: $(this).find(".title").text()
        };
        var url = "/printreceipt/" + obj.classevent_id + "/" + obj.member_id;
        if (obj.classname.indexOf('Kuntosali') !== 0 && obj.classname.indexOf('Virtual') !== 0 && obj.classname.indexOf('Lasten') !== 0) {
            $('.receipt').attr('src', url)
            $('.receipt').get(0).contentWindow.print();
        }
        $(this).find('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Does the event-box contain the form? Any console errors? Show some HTML in a [mcve] - click the `<>` button to create one

Comment: yes event box has multiple forms but with the same form id. jquery allows to print but when i click print dialogue ok button after print form does not print, is it because of focus is on iframe and i want to submit the form on the parent widnow

Answer (score 0):

Apart for the fact that IDs must be unique, if you get more than one form in your find you need to submit the relevant form with

```
$('body').on("click", ".event-box", function (e) {

  $(this).find('form').eq(indexOfTheRelevantForm).submit();
```

or

```
  e.target.closest("form").submit()
```